# Five Second Pause

Tags: java, timer, raspberry-pi

I'm creating a door locking system for a Raspberry Pi. When a user swipes their card the door unlocks using the following code:

```
piface.getRelay(PiFaceRelay.K0).open();
```

I'm trying to create a 5 second delay before the door then locks using the following line:

```
piface.getRelay(PiFaceRelay.K0).close();
```

This is the code that I've used to try and execute a 5 second delay but currently it unlocks then immediately locks again which doesn't provide enough time for a person to physically push a door open:

```
piface.getRelay(PiFaceRelay.K0).open();

Timer autoLockTimer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        piface.getRelay(PiFaceRelay.K0).close();
    }
});

autoLockTimer.setInitialDelay(5000);
autoLockTimer.setRepeats(false);
autoLockTimer.start();
```

I imagine I'm just not using the timer correctly. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which `Timer` class are you using? Based on how it's being constructed, it doesn't look like [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Comment: It's a swing timer:

    import javax.swing.Timer;

Comment: This looks like it should work from a `Timer` perspective - I don't know much about raspberry-pi though - have you tried commenting out the contents of your `actionPerformed` (or adding some logging) to see if it's indeed that particular call to `close` that is being triggered prematurely?

Comment: Just had a look. If you put in a message dialog this only appears after 5 seconds have passed but the relay still closes immediately. I'll have a play with commenting out the door lock command and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the code block posted in the original question worked fine!

However I was also monitoring a database which would automatically fire a lock command if the locked state in the DB was true (which it was) and would immediately execute after the door was unlocked by a card swipe. This was also running on a timer.

The solution was to stop the monitoring command when a user swiped their card then resume monitoring after the 5 seconds of the door being unlocked.

Thanks for your suggestions everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Why not simple (from scratch):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
           piface.getRelay(PiFaceRelay.K0).open();
           Thread.sleep(5000);
           piface.getRelay(PiFaceRelay.K0).close();
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: While useful as another way to do it, this will still have the same results as the original code...

Comment: Yeah I've given this a try, same problem. I'll have a much deeper dig through my code and see if there's something elsewhere causing this to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you got the relay API right? [PiFacExample,java](https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j/blob/master/pi4j-example/src/main/java/PiFaceExample.java) uses 'close' to turn the relay *on*.

Comment: Yeah that bit's fine, the lock is wired up to be 'normal open' (you can reverse the command by wiring it up to 'normal closed') and it does physically unlock then lock, just there's no 5 second pause.